# sbt not picking up artifactory credentials in Github Actions

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory, credentials

I am trying to migrate from SaaS artifactory to OSS self-hosted instance in EKS. I have finished the setup, and while my tests with the self-hosted are successful from terminal, when I try to run a job in GHA, i get back unauthorized or forbidden. Please note that the same sbt/runner setup is working with the Saas Artifactory.

My setup is as follows:
Inside the project folder (e.g. projectA)
.sbtopts:

```
-J-Xms1G
-J-Xmx8G
-J-Xss1024M
-J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048M
-Dsbt.repository.config=project/repositories
-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
-Dsbt.boot.credentials=.sbt/.credentials
-Dsbt.gigahorse=false
```

.sbt/.credentials:

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=artifactory.mydomain.io
user=user_ro
password=some_pass
```

project/repositories:

```
[repositories]
local
local-preloaded-ivy: file:///${sbt.preloaded-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/preloaded/}, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
local-preloaded: file:///${sbt.preloaded-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/preloaded/}
typesafe-ivy-releases: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
sbt-ivy-snapshots: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
sbt-plugins: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
enliven: https://central.enliven.systems/artifactory/sbt-release-local/

my-ivy-proxy-releases-1: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-dev/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
my-maven-proxy-releases-1: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-dev/

my-ivy-proxy-releases-2: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-release/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
my-maven-proxy-releases-2: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-release/

my-ivy-proxy-releases-3: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
my-maven-proxy-releases-3: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts/

my-ivy-proxy-releases-4: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/sbt-maven-remote/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
my-maven-proxy-releases-4: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/sbt-maven-remote/
```

My build.sbt:

```
publishTo := {
  if (isSnapshot.value)
    Some("MyDomain artifactory" at "https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts;build.timestamp=" + new java.util.Date().getTime)
  else Some("MyDomain artifactory" at "https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts")
}
..........
(sys.env.get("JFROG_USER"), sys.env.get("JFROG_PASS")) match {
  case (Some(username), Some(password)) =>
    ConsoleLogger().info(
      s"Using pipeline credentials [user=passwd] [${username.charAt(0)}***=${password.charAt(0)}***]"
    )
    ThisBuild / credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "artifactory.mydomain.io", username, password)
  case _ =>
    ConsoleLogger().info(s"Using read-only credentials.")
    ThisBuild / credentials += Credentials(baseDirectory.value / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
 }
```

For Github actions, I have setup 2 repository secrets in Github:

- JFROG_USER
- JFROG_PASS
  These contain the username/password for user_rw setup in Artifactory.

The action is as follows:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  JFROG_USER: ${{ secrets.JFROG_USER }}
  JFROG_PASS: ${{ secrets.JFROG_PASS }}
..........
      - name: Publish
        run: sbt 'set version := "${{ steps.calculate_version.outputs.version}}"' publish
```

Please have in mind that with this setup (only host/user/pass changed), the action is able to clean compile and publish to SaaS artifactory from my command line and from the runner (github shared runner running ubuntu-latest).
I am also able to clean compile and publish to self-hosted artifactory instance from my command line, but when it comes to the GHA shared-runner, this fails with messages like this:

```
sbt clean compile
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JFROG_USER: ***
    JFROG_PASS: ***
copying runtime jar...
[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.6.2  (this may take some time)...
Error:  [launcher] xsbt.boot.internal.shaded.coursier.error.ResolutionError$Several: Error downloading org.scala-sbt:zinc-compile-core_2.12:1.6.0
  not found: /home/runner/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: /home/runner/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: /home/runner/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/zinc-compile-core_2.12-1.6.0.pom
  not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: https://central.enliven.systems/artifactory/sbt-release-local/org/scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/zinc-compile-core_2.12-1.6.0.pom
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-dev/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-dev/org/scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/zinc-compile-core_2.12-1.6.0.pom
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-release/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-release/org/scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/zinc-compile-core_2.12-1.6.0.pom
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts/org/scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/zinc-compile-core_2.12-1.6.0.pom
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/sbt-maven-remote/org.scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/sbt-maven-remote/org/scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.6.0/zinc-compile-core_2.12-1.6.0.pom
Error downloading com.eed3si9n:sjson-new-core_2.12:0.9.0
  not found: /home/runner/.ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: /home/runner/.sbt/preloaded/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: /home/runner/.sbt/preloaded/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/sjson-new-core_2.12-0.9.0.pom
  not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: https://central.enliven.systems/artifactory/sbt-release-local/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/sjson-new-core_2.12-0.9.0.pom
  not found: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-dev/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-dev/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/sjson-new-core_2.12-0.9.0.pom
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-release/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-sbt-release/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/sjson-new-core_2.12-0.9.0.pom
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/sjson-new-core_2.12-0.9.0.pom
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/sbt-maven-remote/com.eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  forbidden: https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/sbt-maven-remote/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.9.0/sjson-new-core_2.12-0.9.0.pom
```

Any help appreciated, I have come to a point that i feel like I have tried everything...

PS: Artifactory Open source license 7.41.4
PS2: When i try a curl with plain authentication from my terminal or from the runner, like this:
curl -vvv -u user_rw:some_pass https://artifactory.mydomain.io/artifactory/mydomain-artifacts/com/mydomain/common-protobuf_2.13/3.1.0/common-protobuf_2.13-3.1.0.pom
I get 200 OK and the corresponding xml reply